# How can I move from comment to chat?

Tags: support, comment, chat

When I need to discussion to some one about the problem in a detailed way, It seems better to do it in a chat-room instead of comments. But what is the usual way to do this.(I do this once some weeks ago in [TeX.StackExchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145115/how-to-add-new-auto-complete-options-in-texworks) but it was automatically and I want to do this manually.)

Comment: If the "discussion" tag not need necessarily please someone delete it. thanks.

Comment: A new post about a somewhat similar issue: [Retroactively moving comments to chat, when they are no longer relevant, due to edit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24918/retroactively-moving-comments-to-chat-when-they-are-no-longer-relevant-due-to)

Comment: There are also these meta.SO posts: [How can I move a discussion to chat before being prompted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted) and [Should “move-to-chat” be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't move comments from the main site to chat if the automatic mechanism is not triggered, not even moderators can do that.

You can open a new chat room and invite the other user into it, either use the "invite to room" feature in chat or add another comment with a link to the chat room you created. You could also manually copy the comments into chat.